# How to find minimum element of natural number list

Tags: coq

How I can find the smallest element of the list? Is there any build-in function in Coq library that may be use ? I have search list-min but found nothing.

Comment: Where is your list?

Answer (score 0):

```
From Coq Require Import Nat.

Fixpoint min_elem xs :=
  match xs with
  | nil => 0
  | x :: nil => x
  | x :: xs' => Nat.min x (min_elem xs')
  end
.
```

Comment: There is already a defined `min` in `Nat`.

Comment: @ana-borges Thanks, I did edit my answer. :)

Comment: Another option is `Require Import Coq.Lists.List.  Check fold_right Nat.min 0.`